# How to add Cc and Bcc in Amazon SES SendRawEmail?

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

How to add the list of Cc and Bcc recipients in sendrawemail (java). I'm just adding all the recipients to one list and sending the mail. There is no separate method to set Cc and Bcc for SendRawEmailRequest.

Is there any way to set object of Destination type?

```
List<String> receipients = new ArrayList<String>();
receipients.addAll(mailToRecipients);
receipients.addAll(mailCcRecipients);
receipients.addAll(mailBccRecipients);

SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new   SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage).withDestinations(receipients);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Regarding [SendRawEmail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleemail/AmazonSimpleEmailService.html#sendRawEmail%28com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendRawEmailRequest%29), you should be able to differentiate To, Cc, and Bcc destinations by setting them in your raw message headers. If you don't explicitly specify destinations in the request object, the headers will be checked instead. If you do, the headers won't be checked.

Here's a [great example](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=336807#336807) regarding this problem that JustinC@AWS shared on the AWS forums:

> ```
>    Destinations: (empty)
>    To: A@example.com
>    Cc: B@example.com
>    Bcc: C@example.com
> ```
>
> The above message will be sent to all three of A@, B@, C@example.com. 
>      In contrast, if you send the following input:
>
> ```
>    Destinations: A@example.com
>    To: A@example.com
>    Cc: B@example.com
>    Bcc: C@example.com
> ```
>
> That message will be delivered only to A@example.com.